# Override a Magento Class

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I am trying to override the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View with my MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_View in this way:

```
<?php



class MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View {



    /**

     * Add meta information from product to head block

     *

     * @see     Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout()

     * @return  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View

     */

    protected function _prepareLayout() {

        $product = $this->getProduct();

        $logged_in = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn();

        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 

        if($this->checkPrivateCategories($product->getCategoryIds())){

            if($logged_in && $groupId == 1){

#                die('The user can see the product');

            }else{

                header('location: /customer/account/login');

                die;

            } 

        }



        return parent::_prepareLayout();

    }





    private function checkPrivateCategories($categories){

        if(is_array($categories)){

            foreach($categories as $category){



                $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

                /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */

                $collection

                    ->addAttributeToFilter('private', true)

                    ->addIdFilter(array($category))

                    ->load();

                $data = $collection->getData();

                if(!empty($data)){

                    if ($data[0]['private']){ 

                        return true ;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

**I would like to check if the product selected is within a particular category, if the answer is yes I redirect the user to the customer login page.**

Now, if I edit the core class directly the code works correctly. If I try to override the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View with my custom class I get an empty section of the product detail page.  The class has been called correctly, but there is no html answer.

This is the Config.xml extract:

```
         <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>

        </blocks>
```

Does anybody can help me to discover this mistery?

Comment: How you can say it is loading Block class?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you shouldn't be putting this sort of control logic in a Block class. If you follow the MVC pattern then it is better to watch a controller instead and check the category there.

Luckily you don't even need to do that because there is a [free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/635/netzarbeiter_groupscatalog) which already does.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am sorry can't not exactly see what is going wrong. But make sure error reporting is on. Also did you try commenting out some of your code and see if it still works.

Also few things on your code and your approach. The logic you try to implement should be within a controller instead of the view. Also the controller trigger's quite a few events. Maybe there is one that suits your requirements.

The block class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View gets extended by a few more classes. And you don't want to run your check everytime any template gets loaded, espacially since you are querying the database.

Also it looks like the method checkPrivateCategories takes an array of category ids, then uses a foreach loop to query the database for each category id using a collection to find one entity. You should instead query the database once with one collection and then check the result for all.

check $product->getCategoryCollection()

Even so that is probably not the answer you were looking for, I hope it will help